# mongoDB - count the occurrence of a string in records

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm new to MEAN stack. From one of my APIs I manged to get the following JSON as the output.

**GET method :**

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var decoded = jwt.decode(req.query.token);
    User.findById(decoded.user._id, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occurred',
                error: err
            });
        }
        Treatment.find().sort('_id').limit(3)
            .exec(function (err, treatments) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        title: 'An error occurred!',
                        error: err
                    });
                }
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'Success',
                    obj: treatments
                });
            });
    });
});
```

**JSON :**

```
{
    "message": "Success",
    "obj": [
        {
            "_id": "5a3407b5b49aa6268419755f",
            "patient": "5a3393ff963e821dc0f66598",
            "t_date": "2017-12-15T17:30:45.365Z",
            "symptoms": "fever,joint pain,headache,rash",
            "signs": "changing levels of estrogen,dryness,nail breaks",
            "review": ""
        },
        {
            "_id": "5a3407cab49aa62684197562",
            "patient": "5a3393ff963e821dc0f66598",
            "t_date": "2017-12-15T17:35:45.365Z",
            "symptoms": "fever,headache",
            "signs": "nail breaks",
            "review": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

**Question :** 
I need to count how many times a symptom has been appeared in a given date range like the table i attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlHnP.png). How can i count the occurrences? (the symptom field type is string in mongoDB and the symptoms can be vary)

***edit***
I don't have any list/drop down in the client side. it's just a textbox.

Comment: Do you have a `symptoms` list on the client side? You can `split` your string then compare to the list to get the counts?

Comment: no i don't have a list. it's just a textbox. client can type any.

Comment: Then it will not be consistent of what the client can type. You might wanna implement something more efficient and it’s easy with Angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i was able to do it from the following query. I think this will help others who are having the same problem like me.

***mongoDB query***

```
db.treatments.aggregate([
    { $match: { t_date: { $lt: new Date() } } },
    { $project: { sym: { $split:["$symptoms",","] }}},
    { $unwind: "$sym"},
    { $group: { _id: {"symtomp" : "$sym"}, count:{ $sum:1 } } }
])
```

***example mongoDB result***

```
{ "_id" : { "symtomp" : "rash" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "symtomp" : "headache" }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "symtomp" : "joint pain" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "symtomp" : "fever" }, "count" : 2 }
```

Comment: Your data model is wrong. You should not need aggregate + split, you need to use an array for the 'symptoms' field instead.

Comment: what if you have like: 
`"symptoms": ["fever", "joint_pain", "headache", "rash"]`  ?

Answer (score -1):

You will need the symptoms field to be an array of strings to do that easily. Mongodb then allows to search for all documents that contain a specific value in the 'symptoms' field list.

e.g.

```
db.Treatment.find({"symptoms": "headache"}).count()
```

Comment: since i don't have a any kind of list i'm not able to count a specific value

Comment: How do I count different `symptoms` ? like that might be other than a `headache` .Instead of the new query to count that.

Comment: that depends very much on expected load.